# how to add or remove text box dynamic in wordpress contact form?

Tags: wordpress, dynamic, contact-form-7

I need to add and remove textbox dynamically on button click in word-press contact form.
i have tried Forms-3rdparty Dynamic Fields plugin but it did not work.
please give me proper solution for that.
currently i am using contact form 7 plugin.

Comment: Hello , Did you find any solution?